# How to set special character with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv

How to set right special character in SQL with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query

Inserting my data with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. few special character are replace

> “Ee-ock-ee” and “tweet” are examples of this "sounds like" literary
>   device"

TO

> ?Ee-ock-ee? and ?tweet? are examples of this "sounds like" literary
>   device

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html (use the `CHARACTER SET` option).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a character set problem. Read more about the LOAD LOCAL DATA options: [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

sample:

> The server uses the character set indicated by the
>   character_set_database system variable to interpret the information in
>   the file. SET NAMES and the setting of character_set_client do not
>   affect interpretation of input. If the contents of the input file use
>   a character set that differs from the default, it is usually
>   preferable to specify the character set of the file by using the
>   CHARACTER SET clause. A character set of binary specifies “no
>   conversion.”

Note: It is not possible to load data files that use the ucs2, utf16, utf16le, or utf32 character set.

It may be worth double checking that the file is saved in the character set you think it is! Then continue.

```
-- Show all available character sets
SHOW CHARACTER SET;

LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE 'course.txt' INTO TABLE Course
CHARACTER SET swe7
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```