# Cannot import from csv to MySql database

Tags: mysql, csv

I am a CS student. I am recently working on a sample ER model which I am trying to implement with MySql. I want to learn the SQL syntax to import a set of data from a file into a table but I keep getting this error.

I am using wamp virtual server with MySql database.

[this is my csv file]

[image: 1]

[Text view Picture of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcYIQ.png)

[the character set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwF84.png)

So I use LOAD DATA INFILE query :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "data.csv" into table s
```

and this is the result I get :
[result]

[image: 4]

[this is my sup-pro.s table]

[image: 5]

first: why is my integer is showing like \EFBB\ ?

second: is there a way to create a new table while importing ? or we have to prepare our table then import data in it ?

thanks in advance <3

P.S : I used fields terminated by ',' and again I get the same integer format, but with less digits.

Comment: It looks like your CSV file is saved with improper character set. When you do "SAVE AS" for the CSV export ensure that it uses UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450235/how-to-set-special-character-with-load-data-local-infile) might be useful to you.

Comment: ___[this is my csv file]___ Well no, thats an excel view over the .csv file. A csv is a text file, so please show us the raw text

Comment: open your csv in a text editor, excel usually present data differently if it can.and seems like you have hex and excel representing them in decimal format

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html **It is not possible to load data files that use the ucs2, utf16, utf16le, or utf32 character set.** Therefore it is not possible to load CSV files using `LOAD DATA` if they are saved with the UTF16 character set. You should change the files (and your database) to `UTF8mb4`. If you are loading a UTF-8 CSV then this is also an issue as your MySQL is UTF16 so this doesn't correlate.

Comment: it's character set is utf-8

Comment: Show us, dont tell us. Apologise, but we have been told incorrect information hundreds of times before by those that were, at the time, certain they were right.

Comment: I am not sure how u wanted me to show the character set :D but this is the thing that I came up with. I put the screenshot in the Q Body. let me add this that I create this csv file using excel. it was first an xmls format I then saved it as csv utf-8 format. could this be the problem ?

Comment: @MehrdadKhojastefar make a copy of your table. On the copy table change your table and columns to `UTF8mb4_unicode_ci` character set *and* collations. Then try and upload the CSV again. Does this work?

Comment: ??? **xmls** ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's excess information. Its simply the form it was in when the excel loaded it, if excel exports it as a CSV that's enough. XMLS is a proprietory MS Excel format for XML

Comment: @Martin I've tried but got the same result.

Comment: I guess I better insert the data by hand . tnx everyone

Comment: @MehrdadKhojastefar please edit your question and show us Your *Table* collation.